# Can I use App Engine for mobile web and aws for desktop web?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Right now I host my website in AWS and I want to use GCP App Engine in my site. But first I want to try GCP for mobile web. Using the same web domain name.

So like this if user come to  www.my-site.com from desktop then existing web in AWS
but if user come to www.my-site.com from mobile web then use new web app in GCP App Engine

Can I do this? or I have to migrate everything to AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an application load balancer to do this.  The load balancer will inspect the HTTP header and direct traffic based on the rules you provide.

For this specific example you would create a listener rule for the User-Agent field of the HTTP header.

Example header:

```
[
  {
      "Field": "http-header",
      "HttpHeaderConfig": {
          "HttpHeaderName": "User-Agent",
          "Values": ["Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android*"]
      }
  }
]
```

If the User-Agent matches the values you provided in the listener rule then the request will be routed to the destination you provide.

I haven't personally done this but it looks like Amazon's application load balancer supports redirects to on-premise and to other Cloud providers.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html
https://deviceatlas.com/blog/mobile-browser-user-agent-strings